# MariaDB while loop shows syntax error

Tags: sql, while-loop, mariadb

I am just trying to populate a table with some consecutive data but while loop is not working for me:

```
SET @cnt = 0;
set @idx = 0;
SELECT
    @cnt < 40;

WHILE @idx < 10 DO
  set @idx = @idx+1;

    SELECT
        count(*) INTO @cnt
    FROM
        cruge_user;

INSERT INTO cruge_user (
    username,
    email,
    PASSWORD,
    state
)
VALUES
    (
        CONCAT(
            "user",
            CAST((@cnt - 15) AS CHAR)
        ),
        CONCAT(
            "user",
            CONCAT(
                cast((@cnt - 15) AS CHAR),
                "@foo.com.co"
            )
        ),
        "bar",
        1
    );
END
WHILE;
```

I'm not DB expert, just learning some of SQL at this point. I guess I'm missing something.

*EDIT 1:*

This is the error traceback, it shows some kind of syntax error:

```
[SQL]
SET @cnt = 0;
Filas afectadas: 0
Hora: 1.327s

[SQL]
set @idx = 0;
Filas afectadas: 0
Hora: 0.854s

[SQL]
SELECT
    @cnt < 40;
Filas afectadas: 0
Hora: 0.511s

[SQL]


WHILE @idx < 10 DO
  set @idx = @idx+1;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'WHILE @idx < 10 DO
  set @idx = @idx+1' at line 1
```

Comment: Could you provide error traceback?

Comment: Ok, I just added traceback to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHILE` (and certain other statements) can be used *only* in Stored Routines.

Ref:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Rick James is no longer true, and further, it is for mysql, not mariadb.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/programmatic-compound-statements/

Answer (score 1):

Example of running loop in a query outside of a stored proc in MariaDb versions > 10.1.1

```
DELIMITER |
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
    DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE x <= 10 DO
        SET x = x + 1;
        SELECT x;
    END WHILE;
END|
DELIMITER ;
```